# Do you get a 5,000 Bell reward every time you provide the Dream Suite with a new version of your town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have updated the dream town for my Animal Crossing: New Leaf town a couple of times and each time I do I get given 5,000 Bells as a reward. At first I thought it happened when you hadn't provided an update in a while, but lately I seem to get rewarded even if I upload again the next day.

Comment: Ice gave a great answer, but for the sake of completeness: the reason they do this is to keep Nintendo Servers up-to-date and free of old data, thus you should update regularly to ensure your dream is always available to everyone and not deleted :) Also, who doesn't like free bells :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every day (once a day) you get 5,000 Bells for updating your data. Only one character per file can get this data, so... say you have two players in your town, mayor and resident. If resident updates the data on Tuesday, he/she gets the 5,000 Bells. But mayor can't get that 5,000 Bell update reward until Wednesday.

[Thonky](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/dream-suite/) has this information (along with some other Dream Suite stuff, if you need it).